# RMAN archives deletion

Tags: oracle, rman

I have a file system for my archives which gets full in a short span of time. I want RMAN to backup all the archives automatically and delete the archives after backing it up when the archives mount-point gets full.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

```
BACKUP ARCHIVELOG ALL DELETE ALL INPUT;
```

See: [Deleting Archived Redo Logs After Backups in non-CDBs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/rcmbckba.htm#BRADV89524)

Or you can use FRA and configure an archivelog deletion policy:

```
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO BACKED UP 1 TIMES TO DEVICE TYPE DISK';
```

This way when the FRA is getting full, the database will automatically delete already backed up archivelogs.

See: [CONFIGURE delalConf](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RCMRF/rcmsynta009.htm#CHDIFEEE)

Comment: BACKUP ARCHIVELOG ALL DELETE ALL INPUT -- that has to be set in cron for it run at particular times where after backup its deletes the archive logs by itself..but when that has to be run is the question. How will RMAN know that archives file system is full for it run the script??

Comment: @tesla747 That part you have to handle with custom scripts. RMAN will not start a backup job automatically based on the amount of free space in a filesystem.